# How to create silde cardview infinity with animation android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, cardview

How to create silde cardview infinity with animation.

like this

[image]

What's library to recommended ?

thanks!

Comment: check this if you don't want  use third party lib http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/06/carousel-layout-with-viewpager-in.html

Comment: ViewPager, like @NileshRathod suggested, or, and better if you have large number of cards - Horizontal RecyclerView with custom animation.

Comment: check this lib https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager same as you want

Comment: Try these modules, https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow , https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow

Comment: @NileshRathod thanks! it's great

Comment: most welcome @ARR.s happy to help you